# C++ template class to wrap a whatever function

Tags: c++, templates

I want to wrap a function of whatever input/output types.  Below I try to use the C++ template.

```
double foo(double x){return x*x;}

template <typename funct>
class TestFunction{
public:
  TestFunction(const funct& userFunc): f(userFunc){}

private:
  const funct& f;
};


template <typename funct>
TestFunction<funct> createTestFunction(const funct& f){
  return TestFunction<funct>(f);
}


int main(){
  TestFunction<> testFunc=createTestFunction(foo);

}
```

Compiling this program gives me the error message:

```
too few template arguments for class template 'TestFunction'
```

Why C++ compiler fails to infer the type for TestFunction<>? How can I fix it? Thanks. Also, is there a less awkward way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TestFunction<> testFunc = createTestFunction(foo);
```

should be

```
auto testFunc = createTestFunction(foo);
```

Comment: I see. Is there more explicit way?

Comment: Also, why C++ compiler fails to infer the type for TestFunction<>?

Comment: You may replace `auto` by `TestFunction<double (double)>`.

Comment: ...or `TestFunction<decltype(foo)>`. Personally I find `auto` easier to type.

Comment: @Chris What do you mean?

Comment: @zell, When the Concepts TS makes it into the language, that syntax should work to deduce the template arguments while still being explicit about the rest.